# Almost-everywhere support of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $[f] \in L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ where $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space.  How does one define the (a.e.) "support" of $[f]$?  I'm thinking something like
$$
\bigcap \left\{
B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d):\,
\exists f \in [f]: \operatorname{supp}(f)\subseteq B : \mu(B)>0
\right\},
$$
where $[f]$ denotes the usual equivalence class of $f$?

Comment: [Wikipedia: Essential support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support).

Comment: How do these definition compare?  Are they equivalent if $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a Borel measure space?

Comment: Good question. I do not dare to say right off the bat, but I would not be surprised if they were equivalent!